# How do I output the same type of value in VBA next to the same value?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I want to use VBA to get the values of columns A and B and output them to columns C and D as below.

1. Same names in column A are made into one and output to column C.
2. Same values in column B are kept as one and output side by side in column D.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Suzuki | 123 | Suzuki | 123, 456 |
| Suzuki | 456 | Kato | 789 |
| Suzuki | 456 | SAto | 100 |
| Kato | 789 |  |  |
| Kato | 789 |  |  |
| SAto | 100 |  |  |

I'm able to get the same value to one with researching on the internet.
However, I'm unable to output the values in column B side by side.

Here is the code I made myself to combine the same values into one.
Please let me know if you can modify my code or if you have a better way to write the code.

```
VBA
```

```
Sub sample()

    Dim Dic, i As Integer, name As String
    Dim order_number As Long
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Key(キー)とItem(データ)をセットで格納して、リストなどを作成するときに使用。Pythonでいうところのたぶん辞書型

    On Error Resume Next
        
        For i = 1 To 10
        
            name = Cells(i, 1).Value '荷受人の列の名前を1つずつ取得
            order_number = Cells(i, 2).Value '注文番号を1つずつ取得
            
            Dic.Add name, order_number ' Dicに追加していく

        Next i
      
        ' 出力
        For i = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
            mykeys = Dic.Keys
            myItems = Dic.Items
            Range("C" & i + 1).Value = mykeys(i)
            Range("D" & i + 1).Value = myItems(i)
        
            'オブジェクトを開放する
            Set Dic = Nothing

        Next i

End Sub
```

↓ My code output

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Suzuki | 123 | Suzuki | 123 |
| Suzuki | 456 | Kato | 789 |
| Suzuki | 456 | Sato | 100 |
| Kato | 789 |  |  |
| Kato | 789 |  |  |
| Sato | 100 |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only ever call `Add` on the dictionary - you need to check to see if the dictionary already has `name` as a key, and either `Add` a new key or update the existing value.

Try this:

```vb
Sub sample()
    Dim dic As Object, i As Long, name As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim order_number As Long
    
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'loop all rows of data
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        name = Cells(i, 1).Value
        order_number = Cells(i, 2).Value
        If Not dic.exists(name) Then                       'new key?
            dic.Add name, order_number                     'add key and first value
        Else
            dic(name) = dic(name) & "," & order_number     'concatenate new value
        End If
    Next i
    
    DictToRange dic, ws.Range("D1")
    
    'no need to set locally-declared onjects to Nothing...
End Sub

'write keys and values from Dictionary `dic`, starting at `StartCell`
Sub DictToRange(dic As Object, StartCell As Range)
    Dim k, i
    i = 0
    For Each k In dic
        StartCell.Offset(i).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(k, dic(k))
        i = i + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer.
This code is a bit different from what I want. But, I need your code for the future. So I will save it and use it next time.

And the problem was solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sample()
Dim Dic, Dic2, i As Integer, name As String
Dim order_number As Long
Dim tmp_var As Variant
Dim tmp_sp() As String


Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Key(キー)とItem(データ)をセットで格納して、リストなどを作成するときに使用。Pythonでいうところのたぶん辞書型
Set Dic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
    
For i = 1 To 10

    name = Cells(i, 1).Value '荷受人の列の名前を1つずつ取得
    order_number = Cells(i, 2).Value '注文番号を1つずつ取得
    
    Dic.Add name & vbTab & order_number, "" ' Dicに追加していく
Next i


For Each tmp_var In Dic
    tmp_sp = Split(tmp_var, vbTab)
    If Dic2.Exists(tmp_sp(0)) Then
        Dic2.Item(tmp_sp(0)) = Dic2.Item(tmp_sp(0)) & "," & tmp_sp(1)
    Else
        Dic2.Add tmp_sp(0), tmp_sp(1)
    End If
Next

' 出力
myKeys = Dic2.Keys
For i = 0 To Dic2.Count - 1
    Range("C" & i + 1).Value = myKeys(i)
    Range("D" & i + 1).Value = Dic2.Item(myKeys(i))
Next i
'オブジェクトを開放する
Set Dic = Nothing
```

End Sub